# Separable Differential Equation

Tags: calculus

A little trouble with the following problem.

$4x-5y.\sqrt{x^2+1}\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$

I then get to $-5y\,dy = (-4x)/(\sqrt{x^2+1}) dx$

I then integrate both sides and get:

$-(5y^2/2) = -4\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + c$

The initial condition is $y(0) = -4.$

I get $c$ to be $-36$.

I then solve for $y$ and get $\sqrt{(-8\sqrt{x^2+1} - 72)/-5}.$

This is incorrect.

Comment: No, it is correct

Comment: My homework software doesn't agree!

Comment: The initial condition is y(0) = -4 so you will want the negative square root.

Comment: Thank you!!!! This was the problem